# Deploy cookiecutter-django on Netlify

Tags: cookiecutter-django, netlify

Has anyone tried to deploy a cookiecutter-django project on Netlify, or maybe just a Django project? I'm not sure which commands Netlify requires for deploying my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand Netlify is to deploy front-end applications or staticly generated sites. It doesn't provide a back-end environment to run a Python application like Flask or Django. Therfore, it wouldn't make sense to support it in cookiecutter-django.

However, you could use a [static site generator in Python](https://www.netlify.com/docs/#python), like [Pelican](https://blog.getpelican.com/).

Comment: Ahh, that make sense.

Comment: Yup, @Bruno is correct - static sites only on Netlify.  Netlify can reverse proxy to a dynamic site:  https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#proxying in case you have substantial static content and just a few dynamic pages

Comment: @RasmusKierudsen please don't forget to accept my answer if you're happy with it :-) Thanks